# Windows Azure VM availability/Failover steps

Tags: azure

I am trying to setup availability/failover of two virtual machines using availability set. But it forces me to use the load sharing option.

I do not want round robin, the requirement is: only when the first/primary is down, the second/secondary vm should respond.

What are the steps to achieve availability/failover without load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

The availability set is specifically designed for load balancing and high availability. There is no way to turn off the load balancing portion.

It sounds like you're actually looking for something like the [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/). The [Failover](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/) option is what you're looking for. This allows you to have a standby in case the first service goes down.