# How to test that Availability set is working in Azure?

Tags: azure, high-availability

I have 2 Virtual Machines in the same Availability Set under Azure. Let´s call them A and B.
I have created the A first, then cloned the VHD and created the B with that. I can connect to both using RDP and both are the same. Both are under the same domain xxxxx.cloudbox.net as the Cloud service says.

I have a domain testAB.com pointing the the common IP of both, let say 10.0.0.1 for example.  I can connect to testAB.com without any problem.

As far as I understand, if I turn off A, then I should be able to connect to B in a transparent way.
But this is not working and when I try to get testAB.com, B doesn´t get it.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my question is to use the Traffic Manager option in Azure. Nothing to do with availability set. Just follow the Traffic Manager instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/)

Comment: Thx @Dene for updating the link

Answer (score 1):

An availabilty set is not the same thing as a load balancer. When you talk about connecting in a transparent way I think you mean through a load balancer. In that case you need to set up what azure calls load balanced endpoints on each VM, say port 80. Then you should be able to connect via http to both VMs "transparently". Keep in mind that failover is not instantaneous.

Comment: mmm I think that you gave me the keyword that I was missing. That is **failover** :) And with that keyword I have found this other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545651/windows-azure-vm-availability-failover-steps). Do you know how long does it take the failover to work? Thx